# Passing data between two windows forms using visual c++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

1. So, i have a simple forms application : i have a form 1 (**Form1.h**) and a second form (**Form2.h**).
   Form1 consists of a simple *Add User button*(which at this stage does nothing but *opens the form2 and hides form1*).(Till this point , everything works). 
   But when I *add a button "Done" to the Form2* which is supposed to *open form1* again , there are following **errors** :
   left of ->Show must point to class/struct/union/generic type
   f1: undeclared identifier
   Form1: undeclared identifier 
   Please help!
2. the code is :

   ```
   //Project Name: MultipleForms
   //Form1.h
   #ifndef FORM1_H
   #define FORM1_H
   #pragma once
   #include "Form2.h"
   namespace MultipleForms {

       using namespace System;
       using namespace System::ComponentModel;
       using namespace System::Collections;
       using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
       using namespace System::Data;
       using namespace System::Drawing;

       /// <summary>
       /// Summary for Form1
       /// </summary>
       public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
       {
       public:
           Form1(void)
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               //
               //TODO: Add the constructor code here
               //
           }

       protected:
           /// <summary>
           /// Clean up any resources being used.
           /// </summary>
           ~Form1()
           {
               if (components)
               {
                   delete components;
               }
           }
       private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnAddUser;
       private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnExit;
       protected: 

       private:
           /// <summary>
           /// Required designer variable.
           /// </summary>
           System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
           /// <summary>
           /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
           /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
           /// </summary>
           void InitializeComponent(void)
           {
               this->btnAddUser = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
               this->btnExit = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
               this->SuspendLayout();
               // 
               // btnAddUser
               // 
               this->btnAddUser->Location = System::Drawing::Point(78, 44);
               this->btnAddUser->Name = L"btnAddUser";
               this->btnAddUser->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
               this->btnAddUser->TabIndex = 0;
               this->btnAddUser->Text = L"Add User";
               this->btnAddUser->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
               this->btnAddUser->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnAddUser_Click);
               // 
               // btnExit
               // 
               this->btnExit->Location = System::Drawing::Point(263, 136);
               this->btnExit->Name = L"btnExit";
               this->btnExit->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
               this->btnExit->TabIndex = 1;
               this->btnExit->Text = L"Exit";
               this->btnExit->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
               this->btnExit->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnExit_Click);
               // 
               // Form1
               // 
               this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
               this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
               this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(410, 200);
               this->Controls->Add(this->btnExit);
               this->Controls->Add(this->btnAddUser);
               this->Name = L"Form1";
               this->Text = L"Form1";
               this->ResumeLayout(false);

           }
   #pragma endregion
       private: System::Void btnAddUser_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                    Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2();
                    f2->Show();
                    this->Hide();
                }
       private: System::Void btnExit_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                    exit(1);
                }
       };
   }

   #endif

   //Form2.h

   #ifndef FORM2_H
   #define FORM2_H
   #pragma once
   #include "Form1.h"

   #include<stdlib.h>

   namespace MultipleForms {

       using namespace System;
       using namespace System::ComponentModel;
       using namespace System::Collections;
       using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
       using namespace System::Data;
       using namespace System::Drawing;

       /// <summary>
       /// Summary for Form2
       /// </summary>
       public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
       {
       public:
           Form2(void)
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               //
               //TODO: Add the constructor code here
               //
           }

       protected:
           /// <summary>
           /// Clean up any resources being used.
           /// </summary>
           ~Form2()
           {
               if (components)
               {
                   delete components;
               }
           }
       private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnDone;
       protected: 

       protected: 

       private:
           /// <summary>
           /// Required designer variable.
           /// </summary>
           System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
           /// <summary>
           /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
           /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
           /// </summary>
           void InitializeComponent(void)
           {
               this->btnDone = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
               this->SuspendLayout();
               // 
               // btnDone
               // 
               this->btnDone->Location = System::Drawing::Point(98, 110);
               this->btnDone->Name = L"btnDone";
               this->btnDone->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
               this->btnDone->TabIndex = 0;
               this->btnDone->Text = L"Done";
               this->btnDone->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
               this->btnDone->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::btnDone_Click);
               // 
               // Form2
               // 
               this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
               this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
               this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 273);
               this->Controls->Add(this->btnDone);
               this->Name = L"Form2";
               this->Text = L"Form2";
               this->ResumeLayout(false);

           }
   #pragma endregion
       private: System::Void btnDone_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                    Form1^ f1 = gcnew Form1();
                    f1->Show();
                    this->Hide();
                }
       };
   }
   #endif
   ```

Comment: `this` is not needed.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious : so what, i believe it's a good practice always to put this-> .Also, if you have the brains to fix this problem, then please do(i will really appreciate that!) , otherwise there is no need to show your overconfidence even when you don't know anything.

Comment: a guy from the programmers page on stack exchange referred me to stackoverflow saying that this problem would be fixed on stackoverflow given the good programmers on this page.But i really dont see such people around, contrary to my expectations..

Comment: You need to be patient. The most likely reason you haven't gotten any responses is because you didn't tag your question properly. I've added the C++/CLI tag for you.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious thankyou very much for that. I appreciate it. I was just frustrated cause i am not able to solve this problem for 3 hrs now.

Comment: I would add that it's helpful when you can edit your source sample down to demo the issues, and when you can embed comments in the source showing where the errors are.  Otherwise it's TL;DR for many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have mutual inclusion of Form1.h in to Form2.h, and vice versa.  The class definitions for each are thus not fully known before they are needed in the references within btnAddUser_Click and btnDone_Click.  The solution is to define one or both of these out of line (i.e., in a standalone .cpp file).

Comment: Well, i just got a similar solution from the programmers page but still thanx for the help(it worked). Also, i really wish that instead of creating a new form1 from form2, i could use the original form1 instead(like passing the whole form1 to form2).Please help if you can!<br>   Will try to demo down the source and the comments part in future(thnx for d advice)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add "Show" code in form 2. You can just type it in form1. Because when you click that button in form1, form2 is shown and form1 is hidden. next line says that it should again opened. So when you close form2, form1 can be again opened.

But I think that you have the same problem I have that is to communicate in two forms vice versa. I want to know that how can i send one message to form2 and then a message from form2 to form1. I think that you are having the same problem.

Comment: The second half of your answer isn't really an answer. It should be a comment on the original question.